# RPi USB to Serial testing

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, rs485

I have a system like this:
RPi -> FTDI(USB UART IC) -> RS485 transceiver -> RS485 TO USB board -> PC

I'm having some trouble testing RS485 communication between the RPi and the PC.
I'm using a simple python based tutorial: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Tutorial_Series:_Serial

I'm using putty on PC to read 'hello world'. However when I run the python code on RPi, I don't see anything on putty.
I have verified the tty port, COM port, baud rate, and wire connections.

What am I missing?
Please help, thanks.

EDIT: I've attached schematic of USB to RS485 circuit. The USB data lines are connected to the RPi USB. I want to test RS-485 interface functionality. Please advice 
[image]

Comment: Why do you need RS485 Tranreciever and USB convertor? Connect FTDI directly to the PC. Plus I can't see the code so regarding code, I can't comment

Comment: Have you checked your signals with an oscilloscope? Tried any loopback tests to the PC or RPi?

Comment: @MaNyYaCk the custom board has the output from RS485 transceiver. I want to test the functioning of the RS485. The code is is the python snippet in the link. Thanks

Comment: @ElliotAlderson how can i do a loopback test with just a RS485 interface?

Comment: How can anyone advise you if you won't tell use what your "RS485 transceiver" really is, or show a proper schematic of how things are connected. You should be able to do loopback tests on the RPi to at least verify that the FTDI interface is working. How about the oscilloscope testing...what do your signals look like? Can you verify the baud rate?

Comment: If you're going to use RS485, you'll need to operate the transmitter enable appropriately, and only *you* know what that is connected to.  Bear in mind it's not simple since you need to wait until the last bit of the last word is actually clocked out of the UART before disabling it, which typical means a second transmit register empty interrupt that simply isn't present on some hardware (vs the transmit staging register empty or fifo watermark that just about all hardware supports), or a time delay in hardware or software.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I've attached the schematic. Basically I want to test the RS-485 interface. I haven't used the oscilloscope yet. I'm having trouble figuring out how to start.

Comment: For the end you've shown, you're going to need software that operates those CBUS pins appropriately to control the transceiver.  And then you're going to need something that does the same thing for the pi circuit that you still haven't identified.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The CBUS pins are by default configured correctly to control the transceiver(as per the FTDI datasheet). I was thinking about a simple 'hello world' kind of test between the RPi and a PC to test the interface?